# Text overlapping in video processing Matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing, text-extraction, matlab-cvst

I'm a fresher to matlab, and I'm trying to extract text from video using ocr methods. My problem is, there is same text appearing in consecutive frames, and sometimes when camera is panning new parts of already extracted text will reveal and I have to add those to already extracted text. Both makes it difficult to store a text only once if it appear in video once while playing. Text usually are name boards or road side boards having text which are captured in the video. How to solve this problem?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how to solve this problem is my question